# How to convert mysql_real_escape_string to PHP7?

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a Wordpress system running on **PHP 7.0.11** using **Wordpress**. A plugin I want to use does not work and checking the logs does result in

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in…

Looking for this error message I have found that the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) extension was deprecated.

How can I convert this statement to work in PHP 7 and above?

```
$ids = mysql_real_escape_string( $ids );
$result = $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN( $ids )" );
```

I have found this in the Wordpress docs: [`wpdb::_real_escape()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/)

Comment: get an updated version of the plugin? The code looks vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Can I use a `mysqli` extension in Wordpress, as its using `wpdb`? RamRaider the plugin is quite simple and not developed anymore.

Comment: As @RamRaider said, you should update or using another plugin. It's not really secure to not use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Anyway, this plugin seems to not support PHP 7

Comment: I have found this in the wp docs. Is this a Wordpress "work-around" to replace `mysql_real_escape_string` with `real_escape`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress but it seems this function is using `mysql_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` following your current drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use wordpress native function

```
wpdb::_real_escape( string $string )
```

or

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT post_title from $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE %s",
  "%" . $myTitle . "%"
);
```

[find more here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already found this in the documentation. I got problems to apply it. Could you please apply it to my code? (is it `wpdb::` or just `_real_escape` or `real_escape`, as I am not familiar using php)

Comment: you can use prepare() if u want like this $query = $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT post_title from $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE %s",
  "%" . $myTitle . "%"
);

Comment: So the solution is to use an unsupported plugin and change all the functions with prepared statements ? Use this plugin at your own risk..

Comment: real solution is find and replace all mysql_real_escape_string  with esc_sql from your plugin

Comment: @viralbarot Thank you very much! Fixed my problem

Comment: For the non-PHP-savvy, the actual code will look like (assuming you have an older theme, like mine was, that's using a wordpress database handle `$wpdb`: `mysql_escape_string($some_string)` becomes `$wpdb->_real_escape($some_string)` and you have properly abstracted over the WP DB API and not assumed a particular version of PHP!

Comment: wpdb::_real_escape( string $string ) will gave an error: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
so, its properly:
$wpdb->_real_escape()